# Is there any reason to lazy load scripts and styles in javascript singplage app?

Tags: javascript, optimization, load, lazy-loading, loading

Many people convert all js/css files in one global javascript/css file, but still somebodies use lazy loading. Which aproach is more efficient and on what it depends?

Comment: if most people will use the app briefly for one of many capable tasks, lazy loading will save bandwidth and time on the balance. If most users will spend an extended period of time using the app and most of it's features, the up-front cost or preloading will be refunded by the time the app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question, but still...

#### Memory cost

If you are doing a one-page application, you will possibly keep the equivalent of multiple pages loaded simultaneously. It can lead to heavy memory usage.

Deleting parts of the contents (equivalent to what a browser does when reloading a page) can save memory.

#### Loading delays

If you simply fetch the data on demand, the user may be kept gazing at various spinning wheels (the Web 2.0 trademark) waiting for your "lazy" page to load bits of data from a dozen Ajax queries.

One solution to that is not "lazy" caching but prefetch of the necessary data. Typically, your one-page app will load the minimal amount of data to display the first page, and then continue loading the rest of the pages in the background.

#### Efficiency, what's that?

One-page apps should find a sweet spot between loading everything and keeping the user waiting.

Typically, all fixed text contents should be prefeteched as soon as possible.
Images are the most memory-consuming items and shall be dropped out of memory if they begin to occupy too much space.
Variable text (like blog entries) might be dropped out if the amount of text is really big, but usually it is not even necessary to do that.

Comment: I know who flees from the main subject, but reading your reply I would like you to give me your opinion about my lib: https://github.com/brcontainer/defer-images-js thanks

Comment: @Guilherme Mmmm... If I understood correctly, you are loading the images sequentially from within the `<noscript>` tags. While this is indeed better for the server, I think the most efficient way of preloading would be to start the requests before the document is ready, i.e. maintaining a list of images that can be fetched silently as soon as the JavaScript is loaded and inserted into the document when it is ready.

Comment: I agree with your opinion, but the use of my code is to facilitate the development and prevent the obstruction of html and also supports users with javascript turned off. I've been thinking of changing the NOSCRIPT for something else, but this is not yet feasible. Thanks for the review.

Comment: @Guilherme I think that's a pretty good tool to ease noscript-friendly development. The name of your utility could be misleading, though. I would rather have called it "smooth image loader" or something like that.

Comment: Following your advice, that this "smooth-images.js"? Thanks

Comment: your opinion helped me a lot, now my code is giving support for `<figure>` tag and changed the name according to your suggestion. https://github.com/brcontainer/smooth-images-js Thanks!